# NodeJs throws SSL error when connecting to Web API running on Windows server with SSL certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am running Web API server on Windows. It uses certificate and host Web APIs on **https**.

For example, when I put below URL in chrome Browser, it would give list of customer as JSON Array.

```
https://windows-hostname.xyz.com/api/customers
```

Also, when When I put this URL in Chrome browser on any **machines across organization**, it works perfectly fine and returns data. It does **NOT** throw certificate error - because certificate it uses is valid certificate issued by company's certificate issuer.

However, when I write Nodejs program to access same URL. IT throws me SSL error

```
const superagent = require('superagent');
var baseUrl = 'https://windows-hostname.xyz.com';
superagent
    .get(baseUrl + "/api/customers")
    .set("accept", "application/json")
    .end(function(err, resp){
       // throws ERROR - err = Error: unable to get local issuer certificate at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure
    }
```

I have certificate installed (run MMC on windows server->Add/Remove Snap-ins->Select Certificates in left pan->Add to Right pan->Computer Account->) under **"Trusted Root Certification Authorities"**

I could right click on Certificate and exported certificate with .CER extension (BASE-64 encoded). There is no way I could export Private key.

I changed above program to use this exported certificate. Then it throws me **Error: unable to get local issuer certificate at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure**

```
const superagent = require('superagent');
var ca = fs.readFileSync('exported.cer');
var baseUrl = 'https://windows-hostname.xyz.com';
superagent
    .get(baseUrl + "/api/customers")
    .set("accept", "application/json")
    .ca(ca)
    .end(function(err, resp){
       // throws ERROR - err = Error: unable to get local issuer certificate at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure 
    }
```

My question is how do I use this exported .CER file and write nodejs program that can connect to this Web application without SSL Error?

Also, **I must not ignore certificate error**.

Thanks,
Atul

Comment: Possibly the server is not sending the needed chain cert(s), which browsers like Chrome can 'fill in' but software like nodejs cannot. If you have (or get) OpenSSL, try `openssl s_client -connect $hostname:443 -CAfile exported.cer <NUL:` (below 1.1.1 add `-servername $hostname`) and look at the `Verify return code` line near the end. If that shows a similar error, add `-showcerts` to see what the server is actually sending, and either (1) fix the server or (2) extract the missing cert(s) from your browser(s) or fetch them using AIA data in the lower cert(s), and add to the file used for `ca`.

Comment: PS: it's completely correct that your copy of a CA cert in 'Trusted Roots' (or anywhere else) should not and does not have a private key, so you cannot export it because it isn't there. You can see in the Windows displays that its icon does not have a yellow key at the left (only a round seal at the right).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for your efforts and help.
I could solve this problem. it wasn't quite difficult. Basically when I exported certificate as CER file (BASE - 64 encoded) it doesn't include all the certificates in certificate chain. For example issuer certificate was not included.

Therefore, I created single **exported.CER** file that concatenates all the certificates in Certificate chain - including all issuers from top.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXIszCCBpugAwIBAgITKQAANSmJkY5OfHmEGgAAAAA1AAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBB
YYYYMR33333333333333333333YD55555555555555555555LGQBGR11223344553
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes: <Empty Attributes>
subject=DC = com, DC = xyz, DC = domain, CN = Company Root CA
issuer=DC = com, DC = xyz, DC = domain, CN = Company Root CA

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXYYYYYYYYYYwIBAgITKQAAN77777777777777777777TAN1111111111111111
YYYYMRMwEQYKCZImiZPyLG99999999999999999999ImiZPyLGQBGR11223344553
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes: <Empty Attributes>
subject=DC = com, DC = xyz, DC = domain, CN = Issuer

issuer=DC = com, DC = xyz, DC = domain, CN = Company Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXYYYYYYYYYYwIBAgITKQAANSmJkY5OfHmEGgAAAAA1KTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
YYYYMRMwEQYKCZI00011111111111111111111111111111yLGQBGR11223344553
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now my earlier program works when I have .CER file that includes all certificates in certificate chain.

Also we can use following openssl command to get all certificates in chain.

```
 openssl s_client -connect windows-hostname.xyz.com:443  -showcerts
```

This command gives 2 certificates and NOT top level certificate.  I am not sure if it will still work.

Simplest thing is right click and export all certificate in certificate chain and create one file.

Thanks,
Atul